# How can I use rEFInd boot manager without an enter key?

Tags: keyboard, startup, efi

I have a MacBook Air (11-inch, Late 2010) (it’s old I know) and I have installed rEFInd on an USB. The thing is, my <kbd>return</kbd> key does not work, so rEFInd is basically useless. Is there any way rEFInd can be configured to be used without the <kbd>return</kbd> key.

Comment: Any external USB keyboard should work, even a cheap Windows USB keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using one of the following:

- rEFInd does have the ability to work will a mouse. If this does not work automatically, then you may have to edit the `refind.conf` file. This file can be found in the `EFI/BOOT` folder of the EFI volume labeled `ElTorito` on the USB.
- By default, you can make your selection by pressing a number key. So for example, if the first row on the displayed rEFInd menu has three icons, the you can make a selection by pressing either the <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>3</kbd> key. In fact, you can do this before the menu is even displayed.
- The <kbd>return</kbd> key has the ASCII code of 13, which is a control M. So you can substitute pressing the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> key combination for pressing the <kbd>return</kbd> key.

Comment: you’re comment helped a lot thanks. Both the numbers and control+m worked. Unfortunately I’ve only got the usb version of rEFInd so I’m not sure how to edit the rEFInd.conf file. Thanks for your help tho.